# What is the science behind 3d collision relative to the ground?

Tags: physics

To my understanding you have the model of the character and the model of the map.

It seems extremely redundant and process intensive to have to calculate that the ground exerts a force on the player model.

So to my understanding if y coord was less than a certain value then the physics would behave differently.

but what if the map becomes an incline instead of linear? the model would just walk through the ramp into nothingness....

EDIT: i remember a commercial game where you could "sink" if your speed was high enough. So it seems to me like the ground is somehow coded to **exert a force on the player without putting too much work on th cpu**

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a very small map which is literally a box. But the low side of the cube is actually a ramp.

I'm trying to implement collision on the ground so that my model behaves properly. Right now since there is no collision, the model simply sinks to the ground

Comment: Then you should ask about _that_ instead of this broad, vague and unclear question. The more details you put in the question, the better the answers you'll get.

Comment: Applying restitution to keep one object from sinking through the floor is not really a significant cost, when physics engines routinely juggle hundreds of objects with significantly more complicated constraints. Are you sure CPU load is your real problem here? Does your profiling show that this one physics effect is responsible for a substantial slowdown in your game?